# Siemens S5 PLC programmed blinker light doesn't work

Tags: plc, siemens

I was trying to make a Blinking light in an existing program.
That means 500ms on and 500ms off.
This is for alarms and flashlights.

Right now we work with external modules to generate a square wave to make those lights flash and alarms blare.

To reduce cost of making those parts + clear up some room in the cabinet i want to replace it with a program in the S5 plc itself.

But it seems that because i work with delay's the cycle time exceeds the 1 second needed for a on/off cycle of the blinking lights.

The existing program is a single functionblock with 50+ rungs.

Is there another way do this?

Comment: " because i work with delay's the cycle time exceeds the 1 second needed for a on/off cycle of the blinking lights." Can you explain this a little more? The PLC's scan time should be milliseconds.

Comment: it is my best guess to what's going wrong is the cycle time. But what i see is that the lights and alarms blink eratically.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

This example is not built in Siemens, but here's a way to do it.

[image]

1. Create a timer that always runs, set to twice the time you want the light on.
2. When the timer is done (the `.X` bit in Siemens, I believe), reset the timer.
3. While the timer's accumulator is < 500, turn the light on.

Answer (score 0):

I just once again made the waveform with an external component.
The S5 is just too old to get decent information about.

Just wanted to add this if anyone in the future has this problem. Don't try to make it beautifull, just make it work :)